# How can I change Jacksons Configuration when using Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, jackson, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, jsr310

I'm trying to configure Jackson to show JSR 310 instants in ISO 8601 format.

```
@Configuration
class Jackson {

    @Bean
    static ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();
        objectMapper.disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS );
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

However this is not a unique Bean, and realistically I only would like to disable this one setting. So I'm not really wanting to create ObjectMapper, so much as specify a single setting on it.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration$MvcEndpointAdvice': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration$MvcEndpointAdvice.mapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:980)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at com.xenoterracide.example.Application.main(Application.java:9)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration$MvcEndpointAdvice.mapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1079)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
... 24 more
```

Though not really required, here's my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
  <artifactId>modern-spring-web-development</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

and the output of my controller that has an Instant in a Greeting DTO.

```
{"content":"Hello, \"me\"","time":1443886979.716000000}
```

How can I reconfigure just this one setting on the default object mapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can (and probably should) you `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` (in Spring Data Rest 2.4) or `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` which expose the `configureObjectMapper` method.

```
@Configuration
class RepositoryRestAdapterConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS );
    }

}
```

Comment: as a note this is the only method that I've been able to get working in Spring Boot 1.4 + previous methods used do not work.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you could make it more bootify just using jackson auto-configuration properties in application.properties (or application.yml):

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

Comment: nice feature, but I can't see myself wanting to change this configuration in a different environment, (unlike things like show-sql). So configuring it with Java Config seems more appropriate if less terse. changing with properties seems like it would also be more prone to accidental change.

Comment: I think using configuration features enables to avoid boilerplate code and focusing on business logic instead on low-level coding. Also you do not need to create ObjectMapper bean explicitly, spring boot does for you. Just inject it whenever you want.

Comment: obviously I'm not creating it at this point, I wrote a follow up question to why the methods I tried didn't work. You're honestly welcome to that opinion, I like springs `properties`, etc, for some things, just not things that you shouldn't change at deploy time.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation, I found that if I annotate my "setter" (setter injection) with it will get run. This is a little simpler, and cleaner than using field injection and `@PostConstruct`.

```
@Configuration
class Jackson {

   @Autowired
   void configureObjectMapper( final ObjectMapper objectMapper ) {
    objectMapper.disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way could be to inject the `ObjectMapper` in a suitable bean class and then do the setting in a `@PostConstruct` method, e.g.:

```
@Configuration // or @Service or some bean
public class SomeClass ... {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureObjectMapper() {
        objectMapper.disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS );
    }

}
```

Comment: so I tried `@Autowired void configureObjectMapper( ObjectMapper mapper ) { .... }` but it never got called, why does this work and that doesn't?

Comment: Not sure why that did not get called.