# inconsistent org.joda.time.DateTime serialization result when Spring Boot from 1.3.X to 1.4.0

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jodatime, spring-data-rest

After upgrading a Spring Boot upgrade from 1.3.3 to 1.4.0, I have noticed a change of behavior when serializing a org.joda.time.DateTime.

Let's build up a simple Spring boot + Maven Project.

The pom.xml dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

The domain object:

```
@Document(collection="items")
@TypeAlias("item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private DateTime date;

    /* getters/setters omitted */
}
```

The repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String>{}
```

Now, if I GET any item resource, I get the following result:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "id" : "57bf084a452105f14763cce7",
      "date" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8082/items/57bf084a452105f14763cce7"
        },
        "item" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8082/items/57bf084a452105f14763cce7"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  /* omitted links and meta data */
}
```

Which is fine.

Now, if i upgrade Spring Boot to 1.4.0.RELEASE, without touching anything else in my code base, I get the following:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "id" : "57bf084a452105f14763cce7",
      "date" : {
        "content" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8082/items/57bf084a452105f14763cce7"
        },
        "item" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8082/items/57bf084a452105f14763cce7"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  /* links and metadata omitted */
}
```

The datetime is now serialized as *{ "content" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" }* instead of *"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"*

This problem is easily solved by annotating the DateTime field with @JsonFormat:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private DateTime date;
```

Actually, I don't like using @JsonFormat. Instead, I use a custom Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder (it lets me handle my other serializers and deserializers, manually or via @JsonComponent...)

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

        builder.serializerByType(DateTime.class, new DateTimeSerializer());
        
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Bad news, I still get the same result. I've tried with a custom serializer, I still get the "content" key in the way.
Only by using the *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer* instead of the *com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DateTimeSerializer* do I (almost) get what I want:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "id" : "57bf084a452105f14763cce7",
      "date" : "1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8082/items/57bf084a452105f14763cce7"
        },
        "item" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8082/items/57bf084a452105f14763cce7"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  /* links and metadata omitted */
}
```

In a nutshell, what's happening? Where does that extra "content" key come from and should it be there? I'd like to report this bug, but I don't know who is concerned, the developers from Spring Boot, or Jackson?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/39172792/466738 for the same problem

Comment: Try using `JavaTimeModule` and register it with `ObjectMapper`

Comment: Given that the dependency on `jackson-datatype-joda` is declared, it should automatically be configured with the `ObjectMapper`. The issue Marc outlines is the same as I've come across (see link above) and in that case I've explicitly registered the `JodaModule` and it has no effect. This issue seems to be due to a change in Spring since the upgrade to 1.4.0 as in both of our cases the code worked prior to the upgrade.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4.0 upgraded both JodaTime from 2.8.2 to 2.9.4 and Jackson from 2.6.7 to 2.8.1 comparing with Boot 1.3.7. However using raw JodaTime and Jackson gives correct results using either of the versions. See test here: https://gist.github.com/adammichalik/29e4d181409af312adab3a9f4ef6d6fe

Comment: @adam The behavior isn't demonstrated by using Jackson alone. That is, I can serialize the same object with an object mapper and the 'content' field is absent. It seems peculiar to the REST interface. As I mentioned in my post, it seems like the date is being treated as a resource.

Comment: @roborative - yes, I wanted to demonstrate that raw JodaTime + Jackson work fine and it's only messed up when Spring comes to play

Comment: you need to use the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` or some such... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6678 or `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6673

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change Jacksons Configuration when using Spring Data REST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924510/how-can-i-change-jacksons-configuration-when-using-spring-data-rest)

Comment: @AkberChoudhry JavaTimeModule is used for java.time object, not org.joda.time objects such as org.joda.time.DateTime. The thing is the DateTime object are indeed serialized, but the result gets wrapped as a resource, hence the "content" key, as roborative points out.

Comment: I've opened a ticket on this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-888

Comment: Problem solved with Spring  Boot 1.4.1.