# Wrong representation of java.time.Instant fields in Spring Rest API

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

When using the new Java 8 java.time.Instant type on some fields in a MongoDB Document and then exposing that with a @RepositoryRestResource, the fields will be displayed somewhat like this:

```
{
  "createdAt": {
    "content": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

What i would expect them to look like is this:

```
{
  "createdAt": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Check those threads http://stackoverflow.com/q/39170405/5873923, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39172792/5873923.  Which version of Spring/Spring Data MongoDB / Sprint Data Rest (via Spring Boot maybe?) are you using?

Comment: Thank you, I was already at 1.4.1 but upgrading to 1.4.2 did indeed help. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot, you are probably facing an issue that appeared with release [1.4.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1498), and was fixed in release 1.4.1 (or possibly [1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495554/5873923), depending on some annotations being present in your application or not).